# Specific parts of model for drop down list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

This is what I'm trying to accomplish.

Basically I have `Currency` model which contains `ID`,`Name`, `BuyValue`, `MidValue`, `SellValue`, and `DateCreated`.

Now I want to use them in converter I've come up with. It has two drop down lists, where first ddl is **From** which currency is converted and second **To** which currency it is converter. Regular stuff.

The first ddl should always contain `Name` as text in ddl and `BuyValue` as value, whereas second should always contain `Name` as text and `SellValue` as value. Something like this in simple HTML terms.

```
<select id="ddlFirst">
    <option value="BuyValue1">Name1</option>
    <option value="BuyValue2">Name2</option>
    ...
</select>
<select id="ddlSecond">
    <option value="SellValue1">Name1</option>
    <option value="SellValue2">Name2</option>
    ...
</select>
```

*Of course this isn't the code for it, it's just clarifying the explanation above.*
I'm quite a beginner on this matter, and literally have no clue where to start. What gets me the most is should I somehow separate those values into different models and create a view model out of them or could I just use them somehow. To be honest I'm quite confused so any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

```
var currencies = db.Currencies.Where(c => c.DateCreated.Equals(today));
var list = currencies.Select(s => new { s.ID, s.Name, s.BuyValue, s.SellValue }).ToList();

var model = new ConverterViewModel
{
    FromValues = list.Select( x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.BuyValue.ToString(), Text =  x.Name}),
    ToValues = list.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.SellValue.ToString(), Text = x.Name }),
};
```

This comes up empty though. :( And I know it's not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What gets me the most is should I somehow separate those values into
>   different models and create a view model out of them or could I just
>   use them somehow.

Yes, of course, you should define a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string From { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> FromValues { get; set; }

    public string To { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToValues { get; set; }
}
```

and then have a controller action populate this view model and pass it to the view:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    var currencies = _db.Currencies.ToList();
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        FromValues = currencies.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.BuyValue.ToString(), Text = x.Name }),
        ToValues = currencies.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.SellValue.ToString(), Text = x.Name })
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

and finally have a strongly typed view:

```
@model MyViewModel

<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.From)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.From, Model.FromValues)
</div>
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.To)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.To, Model.ToValues)
</div>
```

Comment: I get the following error.
`System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Comment: Did you notice how in my answer I've called `.ToList()` on the `_db.Currencies` instance to eagerly load them? Did you do the same in your code?

Comment: Ahhh completely my fault at this point. I thought that there would be no issue if my *query* for getting currencies was bit different.
`var currencies = db.Currencies.Where(c => c.DateCreated.Equals(today));` And this does change things it seems.

Comment: Updated my question with an attempt. This returns nothing though maybe you can see where I've gone wrong.

Comment: What comes empty? Also why are you projecting your resultset into an anonymous object? That's absolutely unnecessary.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18293/discussion-between-user1407758-and-darin-dimitrov)